# Pandas advanced indexing assignment

Tags: python, pandas

in a Pandas (v0.8.0) `DataFrame` I want to overwrite one slice of columns with another.

The below code throws the listed error.

What would be an efficient alternative method for achieving this?

```
df = DataFrame({'a' : range(0,7),
'b' : np.random.randn(7),
'c' : np.random.randn(7),
'd' : np.random.randn(7),
'e' : np.random.randn(7),
'f' : np.random.randn(7),
'g' : np.random.randn(7)})

# overwrite cols
df.ix[:,'b':'d'] = df.ix[:, 'e':'g']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 68, in __setitem__
self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 98, in   _setitem_with_indexer
raise ValueError('Setting mixed-type DataFrames with '
ValueError: Setting mixed-type DataFrames with array/DataFrame pieces not yet supported
```

---

**Edited**

And as a permutation, how could I also specify a subset of the rows to set

```
df.ix[df['a'] < 3, 'b':'d'] = df.ix[df['a'] < 3, 'e':'g']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that using `.ix[]` returns a view to the actual memory objects for that subset of the DataFrame, rather than a new DataFrame made out of its contents.

Instead use

```
# The left-hand-side does not use .ix, since we're assigning into it.
df[['b','c']] = df.ix[:,'e':'f'].copy()
```

Note that you will need `.copy()` if you are intent on using `.ix` to do the slicing, otherwise it would set columns 'b' and 'c' as *the same objects in memory* as the columns 'e' and 'f', which does not seem like what you want to do here.

Alternatively, to avoid worrying about the copying you, you can just do:

```
df[['b','c']] = df[['e','f']]
```

If the convenience of indexing matters to you, one way to simulate this effect is to write your own function:

```
def col_range(df, col1, col2): 
    return list(dfrm.ix[dfrm.index.values[0],col1:col2].index)
```

Now you could do the following:

```
df[col_range(df,'b','d')] = df.ix[:,'e':'g'].copy()
```

Note: in the definition of `col_range` I used the first index which will select the first row of the data frame. I did this because making a view of the whole data frame just to select a range of columns seems wasteful, whereas one row probably won't matter. Since slicing this way produces a Series, the way to extract the columns is to actually grab the index, and I return them as a list.

**Added for additional row slice request:**

To specify a set of rows in the assignment, you can use `.ix`, but you need to specify just a matrix of values on the right-hand side. Having the structure of a sub-DataFrame on the right-hand side will cause problems.

```
df.ix[0:4,col_range(df,'b','d')] = df.ix[0:4,'e':'g'].values
```

You can replace the `[0:4]` with `[df.index.values[i]:df.index.values[j]]` or `[df.index.values[i] for i in range(N)]` or even with logical values such as `[df['a']>5]` to only get rows where the 'a' column exceeds 5, for example.

The full slice for an example of logical indexing where you want column 'a' bigger than 5 and column 'e' less than 10 might look like this:

```
import numpy as np
my_rows = np.logical_and(df['a'] > 5), df['e'] < 10)
df.ix[my_rows,col_range(df,'b','d')] = df.ix[my_rows,'e':'g'].values
```

In many cases, you will not need to use the `.ix` on the left-hand side (I recommend against it because it only works in some cases and not in others). For instance, something like:

```
df["A"] = np.repeat(False, len(df))
df["A"][df["B"] > 0] = True
```

will work as is, no special `.ix` needed for identifying the rows where the condition is true. The `.ix` seems to be needed on the left when the thing on the right is complicated.

Comment: The col_range function is a good idea as I still want to specify the slices in the columns.  As a permutation, how could I specify a subset of the rows also in the assignment (edited question above).

Comment: Updated the answer with extra info for row slicing.

Comment: Thanks for the update - though When I try df.ix[my_rows,col_range(df,'b','d')] = df.ix[my_rows,'e':'g'].values it throws the ValueError also.